# Why is Chrome telling me there are warning messages but not telling me what they are?

Tags: google-chrome

For the last two or three weeks, the console in Google Chrome occasionally indicates that there are warnings:

[image: warnings icon]

but there are no warning messages in the log.

I am using version 29.0.1547.66 m. Clicking on the warnings icon has no effect, other than to bring up a tooltip saying how many warnings there are.

Is this just a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the debug level to "All" on the console. Also, make sure that all filters are available. I had to select the "CSS" filter to turn it on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my CSS warnings were being filtered too. Now to fix the warnings...